# Reaproveitar função em 2 controllers diferentes

Tags: angularjs

Tenho a mesma função em 2 controllers diferentes.

Isso não é boa prática porque irá complicar a manutenção do código.

Como faço para reaproveitar o mesmo código em diferentes controllers? Utilizando "factory", "service"...?

Descartei a "directive" porque não tenho manipulação do DOM e a função também não depende do DOM, apenas passo um parâmetro e via $http verifico se o registo existe na base de dados, retornando true/false.

Answer (score 1):

O uso de um `service` ou `factory` são as melhores escolhas, pois você pode incorporá-los ao `controller` facilmente.

O esqueleto de um `service` é simples:

```
//Criando o service
angular.module('services', [])
.service('meuService', function() {
  var valor1 = '1';
  this.metodo1 = function () {
    alert('Função' + valor1);
  }
});

//Fazendo uso do service
angular.module('controllers', [])
.controller('meuController', function ($scope, meuService) {
  $("button").click = function () {
    meuService.metodo1();
  };
});
```

O esqueleto de um `factory` já é diferente:

```
//Criando o service por factory
angular.module('services2', [])
.factory('meuService2', function () {
  var service.valor = '1';

  service.funcao = function () {
    alert('Função');
  };

  return service;
});

//Fazendo uso do service
angular.module('controllers2', [])
.controller('meuController2', function ($scope, meuService2) {
  $scope.fun1 = function () {
    meuService2.funcao();
  };
}
```

Comment: Então a diferença entre o factory e service é que o primeiro utiliza o conceito de closure e o segundo não.